# Laravel socialite with passport unsupported grant type

Tags: laravel

I am trying to generate a bearer token with access and refresh tokens after user authenticates with socialite.

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider, EmailConfirmationMailer $mailer)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    if(User::where('email', '=', $user->getEmail())->exists()){
        $exist_user = User::where('email', '=', $user->getEmail())->first();
        Auth::loginUsingId($exist_user->id);
        $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
                'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token',
                'client_id' => 1,
                'client_secret' => 'c4ojSmOjl04QrshdSXlOmbKUOIxm6zqyhND34AT0',
                'scope' => '',
            ],
        ]);
        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    }else{
        //create new user here
    }
}
```

I got the error from vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\AbstractProvider.php
user function, message is "".

```
public function user()
{
    if ($this->hasInvalidState()) {
        throw new InvalidStateException;//here is the highlighted 
    }

    $response = $this->getAccessTokenResponse($this->getCode());

    $user = $this->mapUserToObject($this->getUserByToken(
        $token = Arr::get($response, 'access_token')
    ));

    return $user->setToken($token)
                ->setRefreshToken(Arr::get($response, 'refresh_token'))
                ->setExpiresIn(Arr::get($response, 'expires_in'));
}
```

What is the best practice for this situation? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i tried to directly get the access token by using user->createToken, but i cannot get a refresh token from the $token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resorted to generate accessToken with no refreshToken:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    if(User::where('email', '=', $user->getEmail())->exists()){
        $existUser = User::where('email', '=', $user->getEmail())->first();
        Auth::login($existUser,true);
        //remove existing tokens from user
        $tokenResult = $existUser->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        return \response()->json([
            'token_type'    =>  'Bearer',
            'expires_in'    =>  $tokenResult->token->expires_at->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now()),
            'access_token'  =>  $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'info'          =>  'Existing user'
        ]);
    }else{
        //create new user entry
    }
}
```